# Using grep to find a pattern beginning in a $

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep

I need to find a pattern that starts with a $ is followed by two numbers, a single character that is not a number, and anything else.

I know how to find a pattern starting in a dollar sign and followed by two numbers but I can't figure out how to check for one character that is not a number.

I also need to count how many lines have this pattern.

I have this so far:

```
grep -Ec '\$[0-9][0-9].....
```

I don't know what to do. Can someone please help? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The caret character inverts a selection group, so if `[0-9]` is "match any digit" then `[^0-9]` is "match any non-digit".

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly try this regex `\$[0-9][0-9][^0-9].*`

`\$[0-9][0-9][^0-9].*`

- \$ matches the character $ literally
- [0-9] match a single character present in the list below.
  0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
- [0-9] match a single character present in the list below.
  0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
- [^0-9] match a single character not present in the list below.
  0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
- .* matches any character (except newline)
  Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

Answer (score 0):

I would second @realspirituals answer, and if you need to count how many lines have this pattern, you can count how many lines `grep` ouputs by piping to `wc -l`. In order to both show the lines and count them in one fell swoop, pipe the output like so

```
grep "\$[0-9]{2}[^0-9].*" | tee >(wl -l)
```

where `tee` will split the output between `wl` and `STDOUT`. `{2}` will cause the prior `[0-9]` to match twice.